# Putting text in the top left corner of google sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting, crossword

I'm trying to make a crossword in google sheets, and would like the clue numbers to be as far up in the top left of the cell as possible. Using the normal alignment buttons puts in in the corner, but still further away from the cell edge than I like. Is there way to specify the margins within a cell between text and the borders?

Thanks!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I don't think there's much to modify in Sheets. One workaround, that may be useful thinking it's a game, is to set images in the cells. They can be aligned to the top left and you can personalize the size.

See this example:

> =image("https://scontent.fvdm1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/275794889_10160072514051763_5799695276721854120_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=ko9DsAF71RYAX-ss07H&_nc_ht=scontent.fvdm1-1.fna&oh=00_AfCEncAU0tUu71B6uMjLxzzi0Afvk0QoPQD5_uvCiXyMlg&oe=63742356",4,20,20)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs and Google Slides both allow you to change the cell margins in tables to zero, so assuming that you are just using Sheets for its grid layout you may find it easiest just to use Docs or Slides instead in a case like this.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible and easy. Just change the vertical and horizontal alligns which are in the tool bar 3 icons to the right of the fill. Hope this helps!